# Renaming or rescaling plot ticks to an arbitrary range

Tags: plotting

I am importing data from Excel

```
CorCount75 = 
  Import["D:\CapstoneResearch\75Data.xlsx", {"Data", 2, Range[3, 23],  Range[3, 68]}]
```

The problem that I am facing is with the `Range` parts. When I use

```
 ListPlot3D[CorCount75, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 65}, {0, 21}, All}, 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 21/65, .5}, Boxed -> False, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Xcm", "Ycm" , "cGy"}]`
```

The $x$ and $y$ axes are the values in their respective ranges. What I want to do is rename the $x$-tick values so they range from -32.5 to 32.5 and $y$-tick values so they range -10 tp 10 (essentially, 0 corresponds to -32.5 and 65 to 32.5 and similarly for $y$), while keeping everything else in the plot the same. I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListPlot3D[CorCount75, PlotRange -> {{0, 65}, {0, 21}, All}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 21/65, .5}, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Xcm", "Ycm", "cGy"}, 
 Ticks -> {Charting`FindTicks[{0, 65}, {-32.5, 32.5}], 
   Charting`FindTicks[{0, 21}, {-10, 10}], Automatic}]
```

Comment: This just seems to shift the axes and cut off part of  the graph. What I'm looking for is direct replacement. I made an edit in my original post to clarify.

Comment: @roshoka, please see the new version.

Comment: It worked, thank you.